# How to export Tab Groups

Tags: macos, safari, backup, data-transfer, tabs

[image]

I have to reset a computer I was working with and want to export **Tab Groups**.

When I export Bookmarks (File > Export), the resulting file looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the **Tab Group**, all tabs open as tabs but I cannot copy tabs at the top of the Sidebar.

**I would like to export the Tabs in a Tab Group without having to copy and paste each tab manually.**